# What is the blood status of someone born to two muggle-borns?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that if you can trace wizarding blood in your ancestry three generations, you are pureblood. If you can only trace that back three generations, you are a half blood. If you have Muggle parents, you are a Muggle-born. But what if you have Muggle-born parents? Than what is your blood status?

Comment: "*We know that if you can trace wizarding blood in your ancestry three generations, you are pureblood."* Says who?

Comment: Also: _mumbles mumbles registering account mumbles_ :)